# Problema con formulario: PHP Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string

Tags: formularios, php7

Estoy probando un formulario y me da ese error en la linea 21 que dice:

```
$stat1 = $db->prepare("insert into about values(?,?,?,?,?)");
```

El código es así:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'form';
$user = 'root';
$dbpass = '';


if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $id = uniqid();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $sites = $_POST['sites'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $stat1 = $db->prepare("insert into about values(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stat1->bindParam(1, $id);
    $stat1->bindParam(2, $name);
    $stat1->bindParam(3, $email);
    $stat1->bindParam(4, $phone);
    $stat1->bindParam(5, $address);
    $stat1->execute();
    $stat2 = $db->prepare("insert into account values(?,?,?)");
    $stat2->bindParam(1, $id);
    $stat2->bindParam(2, $username);
    $stat2->bindParam(3, $password);
    $stat2->execute();
    $stat3 = $db->prepare("insert into website values(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stat3->bindParam(1, $id);
    $stat3->bindParam(2, $title);
    $stat3->bindParam(3, $description);
    $stat3->bindParam(4, $sites);
    $stat3->bindParam(5, $category);
    $stat3->execute();
    header('Location: save.php');
}
?>
```

Tengo PHP 7 y lo pruebo en localhost

Comment: Hola Sebastian, te doy la bienvenida por favor termina el [tour] para que obtengas tu primera medalla :)

Comment: de donde obtenes la variable $db, por que al inicio solo veo algunas variables pero no una función de conexión

Comment: En tu código `$db` es una cadena. Para que funcione, **debe ser una instancia de conexión válida**. Dado que se ve que usas métodos de PDO, un ejemplo de conexión válida sería: `$bd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $user, $dbpass);`, donde `prueba` es el nombre de la base de datos; `$user` es el nombre de usuario de la base de datos, y `$dbpass` es la contraseña. Para más detalles, [consulta el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por tu orientación, ya haré lo que me dices y actualizo en caso de ser necesario.

Comment: Aquí: `dbname=prueba` tienes que cambiar `prueba` por el nombre de tu base de datos, si es `form` debes poner entonces: `dbname=form`

Comment: ¿No lo ves ahí: `$bd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $user, $dbpass);`, debes crear la variable así, sustituyendo `prueba` por el nombre de tu base de datos.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta. He cambiado la variable con el nombre de la base de datos, llamándola `$dbname` (línea 2 de la respuesta)  y también en esta línea: `$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";`, es que la variable se llamaba igual que el objeto de conexión que se estaba creando. Si escribes el código como en la respuesta debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás creando una instancia de la conexión.

Prueba haciéndolo así.

He puesto dos configuraciones que te van a ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza:

- `$charset` para evitar problemas de caracteres extraños
- `$arrOptions` con la configuración de dos opciones que permitirán: un manejo correcto de errores (sin esto, en algunos casos se podría revelar tu contraseña en el log  de errores) ; evitar las preparaciones emuladas, que podrían permitir inyección SQL mediante consultas preparadas emuladas.

Este sería el código de conexión:

```
$host = 'localhost';    // o '127.0.0.1' regularmente
$dbname  = 'form';      //aquí el nombre de la base de datos
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
$arrOptions = array(
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
                    );
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $arrOptions);
```

---

O bien así:

```
$host = 'localhost'; // o '127.0.0.1' regularmente
$dbname  = 'form';      //aquí el nombre de la base de datos
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
$arrOptions = array(
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
                      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
                    );
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $arrOptions);
```

---

En cualquiera de los casos, tendrás en `$db` una instancia de la conexión correctamente configurada.

Comment: Muchas gracias (tenia pendiente lo de prevenir la SQL injection). Ahora me da error en la siguiente linea '$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $arrOptions);' y me dice lo siguiente el navegador: 'Uncaught PDOException:' y continua 'PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)'

Comment: @SebastiánContreras los insert como los tienes son seguros en cuanto a Inyección SQL, pero en la configuración de la conexión, establecer las preparaciones emuladas a `FALSE` aumenta la seguridad. Yo expliqué el por qué ampliamente en una respuesta en la pregunta sobre Inyección SQL.

Comment: @SebastiánContreras ¿no habrás cometido algún error tipográfico en alguna parte?